# 2 scripts in one single page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 scripts
1 script is for a nav bar and the other one is for vertical scrolling, but the problem is that the script for nav bar dont work when I insert the vertical scrolling scripp.

Does any one know how to put 2 scripts working at the same time?

nav bar script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-easing-1.3.pack.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-easing-compatibility.1.2.pack.js"></script>
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">.jimgMenu {position:relative;width:630px;height:200px;overflow:hidden;margin-left:20px;}</style>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    // find the elements to be eased and hook the hover event
    $('div.jimgMenu ul li a').hover(function () {

        // if the element is currently being animated (to a easeOut)...
        if ($(this).is(':animated')) {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                width: "310px"
            }, {
                duration: 450,
                easing: "easeOutQuad"
            });
        } else {
            // ease in quickly
            $(this).stop().animate({
                width: "310px"
            }, {
                duration: 400,
                easing: "easeOutQuad"
            });
        }
    }, function () {
        // on hovering out, ease the element out
        if ($(this).is(':animated')) {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                width: "78px"
            }, {
                duration: 400,
                easing: "easeInOutQuad"
            })
        } else {
            // ease out slowly
            $(this).stop('animated:').animate({
                width: "78px"
            }, {
                duration: 450,
                easing: "easeInOutQuad"
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

vertival script:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".contactLink").click(function () {
        if ($("#contactForm").is(":hidden")) {
            $("#contactForm").slideDown("slow");
        } else {
            $("#contactForm").slideUp("slow");
        }
    });
});

function closeForm() {
    $("#messageSent").show("slow");
    setTimeout('$("#messageSent").hide();$("#contactForm").slideUp("slow")', 2000);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    function filterPath(string) {
        return string.replace(/^\//, '')
            .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/, '')
            .replace(/\/$/, '');
    }
    $('a[href*=#]').each(function () {
        if (filterPath(location.pathname) == filterPath(this.pathname) && location.hostname == this.hostname && this.hash.replace(/#/, '')) {
            var $targetId = $(this.hash),
                $targetAnchor = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            var $target = $targetId.length ? $targetId : $targetAnchor.length ? $targetAnchor : false;
            if ($target) {
                var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
                $(this).click(function () {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: targetOffset
                    }, 1000);
                    var d = document.createElement("div");
                    d.style.height = "101%";
                    d.style.overflow = "hidden";
                    document.body.appendChild(d);
                    window.scrollTo(0, scrollToM);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        d.parentNode.removeChild(d);
                    }, 10);
                    return false;
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

ps: my nav bar is fixed

Comment: You are loading 2 versions of jQuery. Can you remove one first ? Then create a fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Why are you including jQuery 3 times from 2 different locations (and at least 2 different versions)?

Comment: No. I need the 2 scripts, im programing the html all in the same page (about some 400lines of code) because  I want the site to scroll, not to link other pages, and the nav bar script, yes i need it, because ny nav bar is fixed

Comment: stick with one version of jQuery, it'll only cause you problems if you don't

Comment: anyway...I must fix it, or there are onther way to solve the problem?

Comment: These people are trying to help you. Only include ONE version of jQuery and place it BEFORE all your other scripts. The latest 1.x version is here: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: come someone tell me if this can work?

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/multiplejava3.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Your second script is overwritting some functions/values of the first script. That is why your scripts do not work together.

1. Try to us the debugger to see what part work and where the script fail.
2. Try to write code that do not create conflits, for example including all data and functions into "classes".
3. Try to write code that only need the html element on which it will perform his task, for example: avoid using parent elements (window.scrollTo).